# How to trace queries to oauth2 server with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How I can enable logs to see actual http queries between my Spring Boot app verifying the tokens and the oauth2 server?

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: https://myhost/idm-services/auth/realms/myrealm
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: myclientid


logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web:
          filter:
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
        security:
            oauth2: TRACE
```

I have this enabled, but I don't see any actual logs to oauth2.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService());
    }

@Bean
public OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
    final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

    return (userRequest) -> {
        OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
        log.debug("User "+oidcUser.toString());
        log.debug("UserInfo "+oidcUser.getUserInfo().toString());
        log.debug("UserClaims "+oidcUser.getClaims().toString());
        log.debug("UserToken "+oidcUser.getIdToken().toString());
        final Map<String, Object> claims = oidcUser.getClaims();
        final JSONArray groups = (JSONArray) claims.get("org_access");

        final Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = groups.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(""+role))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return new DefaultOidcUser(mappedAuthorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());
    };
}
```

there is the security configuration. I'd like to debug the token info transformation in oidcUserService, but the debug lines are not hit during the debug.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `DEBUG` or `TRACE` logs on the package `org.springframework.security.oauth2`

Comment: yes, that's on my logging settings now

Comment: also log the webclient package

Comment: @Toerktumlare how to enable that logging, what packages?

Comment: you check the api and the package says right there at the top https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html

Answer (score 0):

No way to trace in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication`

There are just no logging entries there. The only known stuff is to put all logging to trace, then you will see for example HttpConnection calls to ouath servers, that let you clarify what is going on. It is impossible to trace the tokens and data transmitted, so on the stage where you have no option to debug through the remote port, you have no option to understand what was the problem.